# Where can I get cooking recepies >289 for World of Warcraft

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My current main char is stuck at level 289 cooking.

Where can I buy new recepies, or where can I go to do quests for cooking?

Comment: if you provide the character's class/spec, you might also get some better ideas for food the toon might use (unless you were just leveling it)

Comment: Although I haven't played WoW in a while, I installed some addons should I choose to renew.  One of them is a Recipe finder.  I'll have to look up the name when I get home.

Comment: The Addon you're probably thinking of Powerlord is AckisRecipeList (or it should be, it's the only good one of it's kind.) It can be found at any of the major addon sites.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz:  I just realized I never responded, but yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[WoWhead](http://www.wowhead.com) is really useful for this sort of thing. [Here's a list](http://www.wowhead.com/skill=185) of every cooking recipe in the game, sorted by skill required to cook it. Note that the list displays the skill levels at which the Recipe goes Orange, Yellow, Green, and eventually Grey.

To level cooking between 289 and 300, when, as Dongorath noted, a variety of recipes open up, If you're leveling fishing concurrently, you have lots of options. Try some of these:

- [Baked Salmon](http://www.wowhead.com/item=13949) - Recipe purchased from one of two vendors in Feralas
- [Lobster Stew](http://www.wowhead.com/item=13947) - Recipe purchased from one of two vendors in Feralas
- [Mightfish Steak](http://www.wowhead.com/item=13948) - Offers a Stamina buff as well as health. Bought from the same Feralas vendors.
- There are several recipes such as [Poached Sunscale Salmon](http://www.wowhead.com/item=13946), which won't get you all the way to 300, but are green from 289 to 295. Check the Wowhead list for others.

If you absolutely cannot stand fishing and don't want to buy fish from the AH, you have two options that will see you through to 300:

- [Runn Tim Tuber Surprise](http://www.wowhead.com/item=18267) -  the recipe drops in Dire Maul, as does the required ingredient. Also offers an Intellect buff, nice for spellcasters.
- [Smoked Desert Dumplings](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=24801) -  Quest reward from Cenarion Hold in Silithus, offers a substantial Strength buff that's nice for the leveling Warrior, Death Knight or Paladin.

Another option is [Clamlette Magnifique](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=64054) -  the recipe is a quest reward from [Clamlette Surprise](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=6610) in Gadgetzan -  a quest which was once required to advance beyond 225 cooking. It's easy to miss now that it's no longer required, but it's notable because it requires an extremely common and cheap ingredient (Zesty Clam Meat), offers a universally useful Attack Power and Spell Power buff, and most importantly, is green all the way to 300.

Finally, if you don't mind waiting until November, the in-game Harvest Festival (which occurs around Thanksgiving in the US) will offer you the opportunity to learn to cook [Slow-Roasted Turkey](http://www.wowhead.com/item=44861), along with making available the unique (only found during the holiday) ingredients required for it in abundance. The Turkey recipe is notable in that it will keep giving skillups for a full 75 points, from 280, all the way to a whopping 355, allowing you to nearly completely skip Outland recipes and cooking. This can be handy for a high level player power leveling the skill after the fact, as some of the Outland meat and fish can be a pain to farm.

Comment: I'd go Smoked Desert Dumplings personally.  It's pretty easy to get and you can grind out the mats from all the damn worms in Silithus.

Answer (score 5):

In the Cenarion Hold at Silithus, Calandrath, the Innkeeper, should have a quest for a 285 cooking recipe : Smoked Desert Dumplings (+20 strength).

It might be a chain of quests.

After that, it's directly 300 cooking recipes.